# Spark-elasticsearch fetch filtered records from elasticsearch using spark

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-spark

I have a map which is as follows :

```
 Map("index1" -> List["a", "b", "c"])
```

My data on elastic has a field called "names". I want to query elastic search from spark and return all records which has "a", "b", "c" as the value of the "name" field.

I dont want to hardcode the names in the elastic query.

```
 session.read.format("org.elasticsearch.spark.sql")
  .option("es.query", query)
  .load(indexName)
```

Can someone please help me with framing a dynamic query for the same which accepts a list of strings.

Answer (score 0):

```
 val listOfIds = List("a", "b")
 val strings = listOfIds.mkString("[\"", "\",\"", "\"]")
 val query = s"""{"query":{"filtered":{"query":{"match_all":{}},"filter": 
 {"terms":{"genres":${strings}}}}}"""
```

Used to this and solved it.